# Finding the minimum of a python data array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a variable (my_var) whose values are defined by 3 coordinates. It looks something like the following:

```
my_var.sum
<bound method DataArray.sum of <xarray.DataArray (Time: 18, south_north: 270, west_east: 312)>
dask.array<mean_ag..., shape=(18, 270, 312), dtype=float32, chunksize=(1, 270, 312)>
Coordinates:
* south_north  (south_north) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...
* west_east    (west_east) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 ...
* Time         (Time) datetime64[ns] 2014-11-06T07:00:00 ...
```

How can I find the point where my_var takes its minimum value for a certain Time along with this value?

So far I've tried several versions of min, but I can't seem to make them work.

Comment: Can you give a MWE of the object in question?

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by that? I've googled it and it appears to mean multi-word expression. What does that imply? @innisfree

Comment: Minimum working example, i.e. in this case a snippet of code that makes an object of the same type, shape etc as your my_var

Comment: The object is read directly from a dataset, so I don't know about that

Comment: Not the same data, but same type and shape of object

Comment: `my_var.shape
(18, 270, 312)`
That's the shape of the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `numpy.min` (keyword-argument `axis`) or `min` (keyword-argument `key`), depending on the layout of your data.

If your data is laid out as

```
data = [(attr1, attr2, ...), ...]
```

then use `min(data, key=lambda p: p[0]` to find the minimum with respect to `attr1` for example.

If you have a multi-dimensional array representing your data then I suggest using `numpy.min` while specifying the desired axis.

Comment: It already worked with the min function but would you mind explaining a little about the `key` keyword? Does it just find the minimum respect to an index? There's barely any documentation about it

Comment: Also, I can't seem to make it work using `numpy.min`. Is the `axis` keyword associated to the name of the axis in the dataset? I can't find documentation on this either, there's just documentation for minimum but not for min and they don't seem to be the same function.

Comment: key is a function that is called for every element. In this function, you can extract the correct value from element that you want to find minimum of. Perfect use case for lambda.

Comment: `key` must be a callable taking one argument. Instead of comparing two items directly the results of `key(item)` are compared. However the actual items are left unmodified. `key` is only used to compute the comparison criteria. For `numpy.min`: `axis` specifies the index (or indices) of the axis (axes) that should be taken into account. See `numpy.info(numpy.min)` for more information.